# `500 Command not understood.` from windows IIS FTP server on sending USER command using Java

Tags: java, ftp

This is my first time writing a standardized protocol client so please bear with me.

I'm trying to send a USER command to an ftp server but I keep getting `500 Command not understood.` as a response.

Here's my send function:

```
private static String SendToServer(PrintWriter server_output, BufferedReader server_input, String message)
{
    String server_response = null;
    try {
        server_output.println(message);
        server_response = server_input.readLine();
        if (server_response == null) {
            System.err.println("Error #2: Lost connection");
            return "";
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        System.err.println("Error #9999: Unexpected exception: "+ e.getMessage());
    }
    System.out.println("# " + server_response);

    return server_response.toString();
}
```

Here's how I call the functions:

```
SendToServer(server_out, server_in, ""); //An empty command tries to establish a connection
SendToServer(server_out, server_in, "USER anonymous"); //Tries to "log in" anonymously
```

And here's the output:

```
# 220 Microsoft FTP Service
# 500 Command not understood.
```

The question is: Why am I getting a `500 Command not understood.` response?

EDIT: I'm doing a University assignment so as much as I want to, I cannot use any existing ftp libraries

Comment: Is there a reason you want to code this by hand? There are so many well-known FTP client libraries, for example, Apache Commons [FTPClient](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html)

Comment: Your code seems to be fine. You can try two things: 1) Flushing `PrintWriter` after `println()` call and 2) Try connecting to the server using the same commands in command prompt / shell. In windows, you can do `ftp -n <host>`. This is to ensure it is not a server-side problem.

Comment: I do not see why you think that *"An empty message tries to establish a connection"*? You actually send the empty message. So it's quite probable that the 500 error message is a response to the empty message, not to the `USER` command.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl EDIT: sorry, did some more testing, you were correct. Thanks!

**OLD REPLY:** the way ftp works is that any first message establishes a TCP connection, or to be precise - the server returns a _220 ready_ reply. If I send the USER command first it just interprets it as an attempt to connect and returns a _220_ ignoring whatever command string I sent. (at least that's what the testing and my amateur understanding is showing me)

Comment: An empty message does not 'try to establish a connection'. It isn't even sent. Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: @EJP Note that it's `println`, so it's actually sent (the new line is sent).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @MartinPrikryl for the help!

The first reply `220 Microsoft FTP Service` was actually received after creating a socket.

`500 Command not understood.` was a response to the empty string I sent.

EDIT: `500 Command not understood.` was a response to the "\n" string I sent. "\n" was generated by using `println` in `server_output.println(message);` call